# Typescript - Expression is not callable but fixed by a guard/narrowing

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

Here is my function.

```
export class GetPipe {
    public transform<K, V>(
        list:
            | Array<V>
            | List<V>
            | Map<K, V>
            | ImmutableMap<K, V>,
        id: any,
    ): V | undefined {
        if (Array.isArray(list)) {
            return list[id];
        }

        // remove the comments this to remove the error
        // if (List.isList(list)) {
        //     return list.get(id);
        // }
        return list.get(id);
    }
}
```

`tsc` returns an error for the last call `list.get(id)`.

Any idea why I do need to use that guard to fix the issue ?

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3vo6r7?file=index.ts)

Comment: I don't see anything other than a boilerplate demo in that stackblitz link, maybe you didn't save it?  In any case, could you provide a full [mre] in the text of the question so that navigating to another site isn't necessary for someone to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forget to same the demo link ! It's up-to-date now !

Comment: Ah, the issue here is that `list.get()` is a union of function types each of which is either generic or an overload or both.  The support for calling unions of functions [has documented caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats) whereby it only works if at most one member of the union is generic and at most one member of the union is an overload.  So unfortunately the compiler doesn't know what to do.  Does this make sense? If so I could write up an answer; if not, let me know what is confusing or what I'm missing.